# Crystal Reports error when deployed..Could not load file or assembly 'log4net

Tags: crystal-reports, log4net

Please help.  I have a web application that was built in VS2010 and we are using the CR plugin for 2010 and everything works perfect on our local machines.  When we go to deploy the web application to Server 2008 the application runs fine until we try to get to a report.  When we get to a report we receive...

```
Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

We have installed the CR2010 runtimes and the file log4net.dll version 1.2.10.0 is in the GAC so we are not referencing it in the application.  When we add it as a reference we get this error no matter where we are in the application, not just on the report pages.  Please help!

Answer (score 25):

I received the same error message after accidently installing the x86 version of the crystal reports redist on a x64 machine.

Installing the correct x64 redist fixed the problem - http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0.zip

Comment: It worked me out for me. Still, one more problem. Report shows nothing, it shows blank page.

Comment: App pool Advanced -> Allow 32 bit application (True), enough with no need to install x64 redist as @Matt says

Comment: Just found out that if you installed 64 bit CR runtime, App Pool setting **Allow 32 bit application** must be set to **False**. Likewise, if you installed 32 bit version, then the setting must be set to **True**.

Answer (score 22):

We just ran into the same problem and it turned out to not (in our case) be the version of the Crystal Reports redist (we installed the 32 bit versions on our 64 bit machines.  The way we were able to fix the problem was to

> Navigate to your virtual directory Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> Set `Enable 32-Bit Applications` to True

and changed the managed pipeline mode from Classic to Integrated.  After that we no longer got errors of the missing log4net dll.

Comment: the option is disabled. how to enable it ?

Answer (score 5):

We also had the same issue with the 64-bit redistributable installed. In our case, we set the "Enable 32 Bit Applications" setting to FALSE in the advanced Application Pool properties and that resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks Alan Samet, It is working. I have also set 32-bit to False & it is working. Thank you so much for providing simple way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a x86 development machine and your web server is a 64-bit machine, you may be running into the problem discussed here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/546059a6-7179-4027-8f16-822ac6dc189a/

Visual Studio is automatically deploying a 32-bit log4net.dll into the 64-bit web server, even if you don't have it referenced in your project. Just delete the log4net.dll from your bin directory once deployment has finished because it's not actually required by the CR runtime to work.

Comment: where would i delete it from? from the software or from filezilla?

Answer (score 1):

For me I had a VB Application project and under Compile options, I had "Any CPU" selected for Target CPU and I also had the "Prefer 32-bit" checked.  When the compiled app ran on a 64 bit machine, which only had the x64 runtime installed it could crash with this error, because it tried running as a 32 bit app and wanted the 32 bit runtime.  Unchecking this option and recompiling made it work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Install Crystal Reports for Visual studio Runtime engine for .NET Framework 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problems.

I have 2 NLB 2008 R2 Servers, my IISs are configured to run in x32.

In one server I have installed x64 and x32 SAP redist and I have the error, in second server only the x32 and works.

To get the first server work I uninstalled all versions and reinstalled only x32, but the server start work only after a reboot.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the error while developing with Visual Studio 2022. I did what the other answers here say, installed Runtime 64-bit, because my machine is 64 bit, and then:

- (in Visual Studio) Project Debug Properties > Web > Servers > Change Bitness to x64 (using IIS Express)