# Crystal report errors on server

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-server

I hosted my application on vertual dedicated server.(windows 2008 r2)
All the crystal reports are running on the local host.but after hosting  application, reports are  not working.I installed "CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_1" on the server.error message as below.

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral,  
 PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the 
 file specified.
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Log4net is an error reporting tool and is independent of Crystal Reports.

So, at risk of asking the obvious here but do you have the correct version of the log4net DLL in the Bin folder of your installed app?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How can i find Log4net..?i installed CRRuntime to the server.i searched every where.but Log4net.dll is not in the machine..

Comment: You can find the Log4net DLLs on the Apache [website](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi). Now because you are running Version=1.2.10.0 you will find this on the [Archives Page](http://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/log4net/). When you get the files downloaded add the log4net.dll file to the bin folder of your project. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I download log4net DLL add to my bin folder. but stil shows errors.         Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: TRS - we are getting there. OK, so some futher research now shows it might be an IIS problem. See this [SO link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208516/crystal-reports-error-when-deployed-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-log4net) where people had a similar problem. They talk of reinstalling the 64bit version of CR. That would be my 2nd option. See the third answer on the link's thread about allowing 32-bit applications. You want to make sure that property is set to True on your IIS app under Advanced Settings. Also, make sure to set the correct .NET version in the same area.