# Handle System.OutOfMemoryException while Parsing String to JObject

Tags: c#, json.net

How should handle System.OutOfMemoryException exception while parsing a large string which is coming as an API Response.

I am getting this exception while parsing a large string

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. System.OutOfMemoryException OutOfMemoryException System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.SetLineInfo(IJsonLineInfo lineInfo, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadContentFrom(JsonReader r, JsonLoadSettings settings)
```

This is the simple code that I am running.

```
var jObject= JObject.Parse(responseString);
```

Comment: The exception seems to be rather clear. What is your question?

Comment: How should I parse a large string that could cause this exception?

Comment: what version of Newtonsoft are you using? I've been having problems with 13 (crashing the whole server). So we went back to 12.0.3 and everything is ok again. [see this issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2593)

Comment: is this `responseString` originally a `Stream`? if yes, you might be interested to parse the stream directly, see [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm).

Comment: How large is that string? Are your running as 64bit or 32bit app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Out of memory exception while loading large json file from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955399/out-of-memory-exception-while-loading-large-json-file-from-disk)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the StreamRreader class to parse some of the message at a time.

Comment: this could indeed help: please expand your answer with examples

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).